# Scrapy or Selenium or Mechanize to scrape web data?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, mechanize

I want to scrape some data from a website.

Basically, the website has some tabular display and shows around 50 records. For more records, the user has to click some button which makes an ajax call get & show the next 50 records.

I have previous knowledge of Selenium webdriver(Python). I can do this very quickly in Selenium. But, Selenium is more kind of automation testing tool and it is very slow.

I did some R&D and found that using Scrapy or Mechanize, I can also do the same thing.

Should I go for Scrapy or Mechanize or Selenium for this ?

Comment: You're really looking for opinions.  That isn't the main purpose of this site.  Was there a particular question you had, regarding these options?

Comment: I am really confused as I don't know the other two technology.

Comment: Scraping sites with javascript can get very tricky. Scrapy provides better functionality than Mechanize for large scale web crawling and parsing, but in both cases to scrape a site like yours you have to reverse engineer what the sites does (what request trigger the button, what are the paremeters, the cookies, the payload, etc) and reproduce that in your code.

Comment: you may find selenium to be much faster using `webdriver.PhantomJS` as the driver instead of `webdriver.Firefox` for example

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you to go with a combination of Mechanize and ExecJS (https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) to execute any javascript requests you might come across. I have used those two gems in combination for quite some time now and they do a great job.

You should choose this instead of Selenium, because it it will be a lot faster compared to having to render the entire page in a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I'd choose Scrapy. If you can't handle javascript you can try with Scrapy + splash.
Scrapy is by far the fastest tool for web scraping that I'm aware of.
Good luck!