# Python beautiful soup form input parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My goal is to grab a list of all input names and values. To pair them up and submit the form. The names and values are randomised.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # parsing

html = """
<html>
<head id="Head1"><title>Title Page</title></head>
<body>
    <form id="formS" action="login.asp?dx=" method="post">

    <input type=hidden name=qw1NWJOJi/E8IyqHSHA== value='gDcZHY+nV' >
    <input type=hidden name=sfqwWJOJi/E8DFDHSHB== value='kgDcZHY+n' >
    <input type=hidden name=Jsfqw1NdddfDDSDKKSL== value='rNg4pUhnV' >
    </form>

</body>

</html>
"""

html_proc = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

This bit works fine:

```
print html_proc.find("input", value=True)["value"]
> gDcZHY+nV
```

However the following statements don't work or don't work as hoped:

```
print html_proc.find("input", name=True)["name"]
> TypeError: find() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

print html_proc.findAll("input", value=True, attrs={'value'})
> []  

print html_proc.findAll('input', value=True)
> <input name="qw1NWJOJi/E8IyqHSHA==" type="hidden" value="gDcZHY+nV">
> <input name="sfqwWJOJi/E8DFDHSHB==" type="hidden" value="kgDcZHY+n">
> <input name="Jsfqw1NdddfDDSDKKSL==" type="hidden" value="rNg4pUhnV">
> </input></input></input>, <input name="sfqwWJOJi/E8DFDHSHB==" type="hidden" 
> value="kgDcZHY+n">
> <input name="Jsfqw1NdddfDDSDKKSL==" type="hidden" value="rNg4pUhnV">
> </input></input>, <input name="Jsfqw1NdddfDDSDKKSL==" type="hidden" value="rNg4p
> UhnV"></input>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot submit a form with `BeautifulSoup`, but here's how you can get the list of name,value pairs:

```
print [(element['name'], element['value']) for element in html_proc.find_all('input')]
```

prints:

```
[('qw1NWJOJi/E8IyqHSHA==', 'gDcZHY+nV'), 
 ('sfqwWJOJi/E8DFDHSHB==', 'kgDcZHY+n'), 
 ('Jsfqw1NdddfDDSDKKSL==', 'rNg4pUhnV')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Brilliant. Parsimonious solutions to code are intoxicating.

Comment: When my reputation is higher I'll come back and rate your answer up.

Comment: @sarasimple thanks, but don't worry about it, just glad it helped. Happy web-scraping!

Comment: alcxe, what if I need to submit a form? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 7):

```
d = {e['name']: e.get('value', '') for e in html_proc.find_all('input', {'name': True})}
print(d)
```

prints:

```
{'sfqwWJOJi/E8DFDHSHB==': 'kgDcZHY+n', 
 'qw1NWJOJi/E8IyqHSHA==': 'gDcZHY+nV', 
 'Jsfqw1NdddfDDSDKKSL==': 'rNg4pUhnV'}
```

Building on @alecxe, this avoids KeyErrors, and parses the form into a **dictionary**, more ready for [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250388/673991).

```
url = 'http://example.com/' + html_proc.form['action']
requests.post(url , data=d)
```

Though if this gets any more complicated (cookies, scripts) you might want to [Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259737/673991).

---

The reason for the TypeError is confusion over the first parameter to find() being 'name'.  Instead `html_proc.find("input", attrs={'name': True})`.  Also for the attrs parameter, instead of the set {'value'} use the dictionary `{'value': True}`.